# Implement Google in-app-billing in existing app

Tags: android, installation, in-app-billing

Since one year I develop android apps. I thought it’s time now to do the next step and implement the billing system. Before I implement this new feature in my main app I thought it’s better to test it.

Last week i developed a test app the same app (with v3 billing system) like my main app (without v3 billing system). I published it and installed on my Samsung Note via Google Play. I was being able to buy and to subscribe. And it worked well.
So I deactivated the test app, copied the whole billing methods in my main app, changed the Base64 coded public RSA key and published it.

After installation and start, the app crashed every time.  And the reason is only the billing system because the recent version works without the billing system well. Of course I could replace my main app with a new app which do the same like my main app, but I would lose all my user, my statistics and comments until now.
Do you know why my app cannot install the billing system with the RSA key?
Which other reasons could be responsible for this Situation?

what happens in onCreate:

```
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(false);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
```

and what happens in line 960:

```
    public IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished .");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        // Purchase premium monthly
        Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.PREMIUM);
        if(purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PURCHASED_SUCCESSFULLY && verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)){
            isPremium = true;
        }else{
            isPremium = false;
            updatePremium(purchase.getPurchaseState());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "User " + (isPremium ? "HAS" : "DOES NOT HAVE") + " premium surebets for 32 days.");

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

at package.Surebets$1.onQueryInventoryFinished(Surebets.java:960)

at package.billing.IabHelper$2$1.run(IabHelper.java:607)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

...

and on startup:

Error checking for billing v3 support

Comment: null exception in the line Surebets.java:960, can you post this part

Comment: Now, I solved it by my self. If I call getPurchase(...) and the customer doesn't buy the in-app item it returns null. In the next line i call purchase.getPurchaseState() and of course it throws a NPE. I add null check and so it was solved.